# How to pass data to root controller from one of the sub controller and dismiss all the sub controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have 4 view controllers lets say A, B, C, and D  and all these view controllers will be pushed as A->B->C->D.

I have a Dictionary in 'D' and I need to pass this to Dictionary 'A' and I need to Dismiss all the controllers except 'A' Controller to do some action with that received data passed from 'D'.

What are the approaches to pass data between view controllers and dismiss all sub controllers as per my requirement?

Comment: just read it again

Comment: read the duplicated please in all form of passing data from one viewcontroller to another and the notification one is suitable for this purspose

Comment: u said right, how about dismissing the sub-controllers.

Comment: there are ways to do that but i guess you're using a navigation viewcontroller so you could call `self..navigationController.popToViewController`

Comment: thanks, u read well my question, this is what I am missing, and  I am looking for pice of code.

Answer (score 0):

In ViewController A, in ViewDidLoad create notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(getDictionaryFromD:)
                                                 name:@"getDictionaryFromD" object:nil];
```

Next implement this method in View Controller A

```
-(void)getDictionaryFromD:(NSNotification*)notify {
   [[[[self view]window]rootViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];
    NSDictionary *dict = [notify object];
}
```

Now in view Controller D pass dict by calling this notification like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"deviceWidthChange" object:WHDict];
```

Comment: how about dismissing the sub-controllers